# Timely send push notifications with flutter

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

I have to send push notifications timely in flutter. I have a list of my tasks and  I want that app should notify me against each task using time and date. Currently I am using `firebase` to store my tasks . and here is my code ..

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _dateText = "${_dueDate.day}/${_dueDate.month}/${_dueDate.year}";
    _timeText = "${_time.hour}:${_time.minute}";
    menuDataList = [
      new MenuData(Icons.add, (context, menuData) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new AddTask(email: widget.user.email)));

      }
      ,labelText: 'Add Task'
      ),
      new MenuData(Icons.group_add, (context, menuData) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new AddGroup(email: widget.user.email)));
      }
      ,labelText: 'Add Group'
      ),
      new MenuData(Icons.group, (context, menuData) {

        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new CreateGroup(email: widget.user.email  )));
      }
      ,labelText: 'View Group'
      ),
      new MenuData(Icons.search, (context, menuData) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new MySearchPage()));
      }
          ,labelText: 'Search Here'
      ),
    ];
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var ios = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var platform = new InitializationSettings(android , ios);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(platform);
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(

      onMessage: (Map<String , dynamic> message){
        showNotification(message);
        print('on message $message');

//        AudioCache player = new AudioCache();
//        const alarmAudioPath = "sounds/notification.mp3";
//        player.play(alarmAudioPath);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String , dynamic> message){
        showNotification(message);
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String , dynamic> message){
        showNotification(message);
        print('on message $message');
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      print(token);
    });
  }

  showNotification(Map<String , dynamic> message) async{
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails('channel_id' , "CHANNAL NAME" , "channelDescription");
    var ios = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, ios);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, note , newtask , platform);
  }
```

And here is the code of my list where I am showing my tasks.

```
class TaskList extends StatelessWidget{
  TaskList({this.document});
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> document;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: document.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext  , int i ){
        String title = document[i].data['title'].toString();
        String note = document[i].data['note'].toString();
        DateTime _date = document[i].data['duedate'];
        String duedate = "${_date.day}/${_date.month}/${_date.year}";
//        String email = document[i].data['email'].toString();

        return new Dismissible(
          key: new Key(document[i].documentID),
          onDismissed: (direction){
            Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async{
              DocumentSnapshot snapshot= await transaction.get(document[i].reference);
              await transaction.delete(snapshot.reference);

            });

            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("Data Deleted"),));
          },

          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 0.0 ,right: 0.0 , bottom: 16.0 ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                  child: new Align( alignment: Alignment.topLeft ,
                    child: new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.lens , color: Colors.black87, size: 12.0,), onPressed: (
                        ){
                    },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                          child: Text(title , style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0 , letterSpacing: 1.0),),
                        ),
                        new Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0 , top: 3.0 , bottom: 3.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.date_range , color: Colors.black54, size: 17.0),
                            ),
                           new Expanded(child: Text(duedate , style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0 ),)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        new Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.note , color: Colors.black54, size: 17.0,),
                            ),
                            new Expanded(child: Text(note , style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0 ),)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),

                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                  child: new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit , color: Colors.black54,), onPressed: (
                      ){
                     Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new EditTask(
                       title: title,
                       note: note,
                       duedate: document[i].data['duedate'],
                       index:document[i].reference,
                     )));
                  },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );

      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There exists different types of notification on mobile developement. Specifically you could have remote and local notification. You are asking for timely (scheduled I guess) *push* notifications (that are kinda remote notifications). So according to what you're asking that's a business logic  to be added to your server and not to your client app. Instead if you wanna use local notifications I suggest to use a plugin like [that](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications) and schedule local notifications based on your task date and time.

Comment: Let me know what's your need: local or remote?

Comment: @shadowsheep i want remote notification like every task i set or any user set for his self app should send a notification on that particular task time

Comment: I would suggest to schedule local notifications for this, because you already have on device your tasks with their date. Local notification doesn't need a network connection and you don't spend resources to send remote notiifcation. Btw if you wanna send remote notification on your server side you must schedule a cron job that call [FCM api rest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to the device token accordingly to its task scheduling. If you are using firebase cloud function you must follow Sam asnwer, because you cannot setup a cron job cloud function nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no direct support for schedule a function call that sends notifications to user. But you can use third party services that will call your function remotely and then you can send notifications to the users.

Comment: which third party service would you recommend?

Comment: Below are the two services I know.
https://cron-job.org/en/  and  
https://www.easycron.com/

Or if you have a PHP site you can just create a CRON job to hit your firebase cloud function and it will do the job.